# Про «Кощей Бессмертный» українською

Tags: переклад, from-russian, власні-назви, іноземні-імена

Я чув про три варіанти різного ступеню серйозності:

- Кощій Безсмертний;
- Костій Бездушний;
- Чахлик Невмирущий.

**Цікаві (для кожного варіанту)**:

- **історія походження**;
- **контекст вживання**;
- **сфера прийнятності**.

Також незрозуміло, чи останній варіант виключно гумористичним, чи може вживатися в серйозних контекстах.

Answer (score 15):

Ось що пише М. Грушевський ("Історія української літератури"):

> «***Кощій безсмертний***» — образ, паралельний змієві: в казках і билинах сі
>   два образи нераз заступають себе навзаєм, але в українській традиції
>   Кощій ослаб, і ті казки, в котрих він приходить («бездушний Костій» —
>   варіант дуже солдатського типу), можуть бути новішими зайдами з
>   Великоросії. Одначе нема сумніву, що маємо тут образ старий, місцевий,
>   і ті повніші варіанти сього мотиву, які знаходимо в Великоросії і в
>   іншім слов’янськім та скандинавськім фольклорі, щонайменше — належать
>   до нашої київської доби.

Власне, на українських теренах поширенішим був варіант "**бездушний**", а в російському фольклорі - "**безсмертний**": у яйці була його душа в першому випадку і смерть - в другому. Ось доказ (П.Кузьмичевскій "Шолудивый Буняка въ украинскихъ народныхъ сказаніяхъ"):

> образъ этотъ и имя чаще встрѣчается въ сказкахъ великорусскихъ, чѣмъ
>   въ украинскихъ, изъ которыхъ пока напечатаны только одна съ именемъ
>   Костія (у Чубинскаго, т. II, отд. I, №64). Въ великорусскихъ сказкахъ
>   Кощей является по большей части похитителемъ красавицъ, а безсмертнымъ
>   онъ называется потому, что смерть его запрятана далеко и въ очень
>   сложномъ аппаратѣ: въ яйцѣ, которое спрятано въ уткѣ, а утка въ зайцѣ,
>   а заяцъ въ сундукѣ, сундукъ на деревѣ и т.п. Красавица успѣваетъ
>   выпытать секретъ Кощея, герой добываетъ фатальное яйцо и Кощей
>   погибаетъ. Украинская сказка съ именемъ Костія принадлежитъ къ другой
>   фабулѣ (Иванъ Богодавецъ, похожденія чудесно рожденнаго сына долго
>   бездѣтныхъ родителей, который здѣсь между прочимъ самъ съ товарищами
>   захватываетъ дочекъ Костія). Костій здѣсь называется бездушнымъ, такъ
>   какъ душа его спрятана въ яйцѣ, яйцо въ уткѣ, утка въ гнѣздѣ на дубѣ.

За етимологічним словником:

> слово "**кощій**" - похідне від дієслова "*костити*" - поганити, оскверняти,
>   паплюжити - від праслов'янського *кость* (гидота, труп) - така версія
>   добре підходить для казкової істоти, що викрадає й оскверняє дівчат.
>   Пізніше це слово набуло значення худої кістлявої людини (можливо,
>   через зближення з іменником "*кістка*").
>
> Ще один варіант етимології: в тюркських мовах слово "**кощій**" означало
>   невільника, раба, отрока. 
>   Ніби не дуже підходить для казкової версії (хоча якщо вважати Кощія рабом яйця...)

До речі, колись на Русі специфічні пісні духовного змісту (зокрема, їх виконували на тризнах) називали "*кощунами*", а співців, котрі їх виконували - *кощунниками*. У християнську добу такі речі, звісно ж, стали забороненими, звідси російське дієслово "*кощунствовать*" на позначення дій, пов'язаних з оскверненням святині, порушенням заборон.

Костій Бездушний згадується у книгах "100 найвідоміших образів української міфології" та "Основи української літературно-наукової критики", отже, він таки був і є.

Щодо Чахлика Невмирущого - це фікція. [Шолудивий Буняк](http://iht.univ.kiev.ua/library/ks/1887/kievskaya-starina-1887-10-B-%284652-4695%29.pdf) існує, Чахлик - ні.

Comment: Раніше я думав, що «Чахлик Невмирущий» — це просто жарт. Або над недолугими перекладачами (що намагаються калькувати те, що не треба калькувати), або українською мовою взагалі (наприклад, з боку росіян) чи певними тенденціями в ній (наприклад, невдалими спробами 90-х розширити лексикон). Але побачив його, наприклад, [тут](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=vTw7AQAAIAAJ) — без усілякого жартівливого контексту. От і думаю — що це таке, звідки воно взагалі взялося?

Comment: @Sasha, це і є жарт, бо в жодній авторитетній праці з фольклористики ви не знайдете Чахлика. Буде Кощій, буде Костій, але не ця потвора. 
Де воно взялося? Підозрюю, там само, де й "розчепірка", "спалахуйка" і "міжповерховий дротохід". Сумнівна і чого етимологія: українською "чахлик" - це різновид сорочки, навряд чи таке закріпилося б у народній свідомості на позначення осквернителя дівчат, погодьтеся. Спадає на думку лише одне - той, що "над златом чахнет", а це вже зовсім інша історія.

Comment: А чого воно тоді використовується в [дитячих постановках](http://blogiryny.blogspot.com/p/blog-page_55.html), [серйозних віршах](http://web.archive.org/web/20160823220423/http://elina.dn.ua/pdf/progal2/Pustelni_ribi.pdf) і [львівських журналах 1990 року видання](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=vTw7AQAAIAAJ)? Ну, добре, перше зрозуміло — вихователі не завжди освічені люди, жарт за правду прийняли. Ну зі Свенцицькою, припустимо, теж здогадуємось письменниця російського походження. Але чому в «Дзвоні» 90 року? Це ж навіть до 90х, коли оці «спалахуйки» (і, відповідно, глуз над ними) почались?

Comment: @Sasha, у мене була версія з невгамовними пуристами, але навряд. Можливо, вони просто не чули про "Костія", а "Кощій" здався їм недостатньо українізованим?

Comment: І так, у тому серйозному вірші це навіть не загальна назва. Сумніваюся, що взагалі йшлося про фольклорного персонажа.

Comment: Можливо. Просто якщо в 1990 році це слово вжито в нейтральному контексті (хоча й поряд з Кощеєм Безсмертним) у статті не про нього (а як метафору), то, мабуть, історія цього словосполучення ще довша (тобто, щоби його використали в журналі як метафору, мабуть, хтось ще раніше має використати його *не* як метафору). Щодо «Пустельних риб» — я думаю, це була відсилка саме до нього, хоча й з метою підкреслення не тих рис, що він мав як казкрвий персонаж, а радше тих, що містяться безпосередньо в словосполученні. (Хоча, так, вірші — то таке, зовсім незрозуміло.) Текст «Дзвону» Вам видно, чи дістати?

Comment: @Sasha, у тому й річ, що не видно. Можливо, контекст би щось пояснив.

Comment: Текст там жартівливий:
https://books.google.com.ua/books?hl=ru&id=vTw7AQAAIAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA

Answer (score 3):

Брат Капранов ві [свойому видиві](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y0uMJ9hU6VU) зі вказом на [вживані материяли](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1p78V69L5PVjc8oIEOuNIXEDuYxrdi0u5xp6-czQge94/edit) каже, же *Кощей* — то штибу Московською сучасне Українське **Кошовий**, ще з часів Орди, коли Москалї з Ордою воювали проти Половцїв і нас.

Саме́ слово *кощій* також згадує ся ві, згаданому ві видиві, творі про Половцїв, ві [Слово о полку Ігоревім](http://litopys.org.ua/slovo67/sl01_1.htm):

> Ту́ И́горь кня̀зь вы́сѣдѣ изъ сѣдла́ зла́та
> а въ сѣдло́ *кощі́ево*.
>
> ---
>
> Аже бы ты́ бы́лъ,
> то была̀ бы ча́га по нога́тѣ,
> а *коще́и* — по реза́нѣ.
>
> ---
>
> Стрѣля́и, господи́не, Конча́ка,
> пога́ного *коще́я*,
> за зе́млю Ру́скую,
> за ра́ны И́горевы,
> бу́его Святъсла́влича!

Увага, заміни:

- *ђ* на *ѣ*, котрого не змогли позначити через [технічні проблєми](http://litopys.org.ua/ukrmova/um150.htm)
- латиниця на кирилицю з окремими наголосами

Answer (score 1):

Додам ще можливі варіанти.

Відповідно до [Російсько-українського народного сучасного словника](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on):

> Кощей, Кащей – (очень костлявый) кощій, (шутл.) чахлик; (в сказках)
>   Косте́й, цар-Косте́й, Кощі́й, Коще́й, (скупец) скна́ра, скупердя́,
>   скупердя́га, скупи́ндя; лихва́р: • **Кощей бессмертный** – Кощій
>   безсмертний, (насм.) Чахлик невмирущий.

Згідно з працею "[Шолудивый Буняка в украинский народных сказаниях](http://iht.univ.kiev.ua/library/ks/1887/kievskaya-starina-1887-10-B-%284652-4695%29.pdf)", то можливий варіант "[Костій Бездушний](http://iht.univ.kiev.ua/library/ks/1887/kievskaya-starina-1887-10-B-%284652-4695%29.pdf)" (ст.37 ПДФ).

[Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9#cite_note-%D0%91%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%B0-1) посилаючись на ЕСУМ та на статтю "Боги древніх слов'ян" дає цілих три версії походження імені:

Щодо походження слова «кощій» висунуто кілька версій.

> Згідно з першою, слово «кощій» походить від давньорус. костити («поганити», «бруднити», «паплюжити», «сквернити»), яке пов'язане з
>   прасл. *kostь («гидота» — з первісного значення «труп», «падло»). Пор.
>   укр. костити («брудно лаяти»), рос. кощун («блюзнір»), кощунство
>   («блюзнірство»), кащёнок («мерзотник»), біл. касціць
>   («випорожнятися»). Тобто, «Кощій» — «паплюжник», «осквернитель», що
>   узгоджується з його казковим образом викрадача та мучителя прекрасних
>   дівчат.
>
> Згідно з другою, імена «Кощій» та «Костій» пов'язуються зі словами «кощавий», «кістка». Закінчення -ій при іменниковому корені слова
>   позначає рясність, велику кількість: «губій», «чубій» тощо. Проте,
>   прибічники першої версії припускають, що подібне значення є вторинним,
>   викликаним пізнішим перетлумаченням незрозумілого слова «кощій».
>   Прихильники ж теорії значення «кістлявий» відслідковують протилежний
>   процес деетимологізації з поширенням слова зі заходу на схід: від
>   Kościej в польських та Костій в українських казках до Кош та Кот в
>   російських народних казках.
>
> Згідно з третьою версією, слово «кощій» тюркського походження: від слова košci («раб», «невільник», «отрок»).

До речі, також вдалося знайти цікаві слова про варіант "Чахлик Невмирущий" у книзі "Полювання на дрохв" Петра Лущика:

> Чахлик Невмирущий - це Кощій Безсмертний, який прийняв українське
>   громадянство. На початку дев'яностих, на зорі незалежності України, на
>   українську мову перекладали все, що потрапляло під руку. Навіть
>   замість футболу казали "копаний м'яч".

Comment: [_Ко́панка_](https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=219163&page=1390) — старе і затверџене словником слово, котре було вживано до Червонойе̂ навали. Гинше̂ Словяни теж мають власне̂ назви, декотре̂ наве̂ть як за основну: Ч. [kopaná](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fotbal "копана̄"), Свн., Х. [nogomet](https://sl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nogomet "ноґомет"), П. [piłka nożna](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piłka_nożna "півка ножна").